# Changing the new array name in the loop

Tags: arrays, perl

How to change the name of an array to place in it another item

```
 @array=("1, 2, 3, 4", "5, 6, 7, 8");
 $c=0;
 foreach $x(@array){
      push ("@value_$c", split(", ", $x));
      $c++;}
```

So the output should be like this:

```
 @value_0=(1,2,3,4)
 @value_1=(5,6,7,8)
```

PS: I know it is not correct to write "@value_$c"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use hash,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = ("1, 2, 3, 4", "5, 6, 7, 8");

my %hash;
foreach my $c (0 .. $#array) {

  push @{$hash{"value_$c"}}, split(/, /, $array[$c]);
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'value_1' => [
                     '5',
                     '6',
                     '7',
                     '8'
                   ],
      'value_0' => [
                     '1',
                     '2',
                     '3',
                     '4'
                   ]
    };
```

or use two dimensional array,

```
my @result;
foreach my $c (0 .. $#array) {

  push @result, [ split(/, /, $array[$c]) ];
}
```

Comment: Although this is most likely the solution the OP desires, I would suggest that an array or arrays would be more appropriate, the `list_idx => list_value` data structure design is rarely necessary.